# After adding an element to the DOM it doesn't run the same functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('button').each(function(i){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).after('<br /><button type="button">Button</button>');
        });
    });
});
</script>
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

If i click the button it works and adds a button after it. I can keep clicking the same button and adding more buttons. But if I click any of the buttons that have been added they don't add anything. I tried changing to:

```
    $(function(){
    function update(){
        $('button').each(function(i){
            $(this).click(function(){
                $(this).after('<br /><button type="button">Button</button>');
                update();
            });
        });
    };
    update();
});
```

But this selects the first button twice so if i press it once it works and so does the button it adds but if i press the first button a second time it adds 2 more buttons and then 4 more etc..

Comment: this question has been asked at least 3 times yesterday... we should close this as duplicate instead of trying to get easy reputation

Comment: @Pablo so sick of this `!@#$ing` question.

Comment: To extend what Pablo has said, please use the search function!

Comment: @Matt it's a good question, the thing is that it's been asked again and again and again. We must find the best answer we can and start pointing the users there *cough* moderators *cough*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use event delegation to manage the click events.

```
$('body').delegate('button','click',function() {
    $(this).after('<br /><button type="button">Button</button>');
});
```

This uses the [`delegate()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method to handle all clicks that take place in the `<body>` and are preformed on elements matching the `'button'` selector.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/Krrae/

If all your buttons are in a common container (other than `<body>`), then use that for the delegate instead:

```
$('#some_button_container').delegate('button','click',function() {
    $(this).after('<br /><button type="button">Button</button>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try using [jQuery delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [jQuery live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).  I would suggest delegate first.

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery .live() function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) takes care of this of this for you. It allows you to add events to **all current and future** elements that match the class you specify.

Answer (score 2):

You need `.live()` or `.delegate()`, since your code binds only those elements that are in the DOM at the point/time of execution, and you're looking for all buttons, even those that do not exist yet.

For example (http://jsfiddle.net/5RWrW/):

```
$(function(){
    $('button').live('click', function(){
        $(this).after('<br /><button type="button">Button</button>');
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you could create the new element and add a new/separate event listener, although that seems harder and more wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to attach event handlers to all current and future elements:

Comment: `.live()` doesn't attached to future elements. It attaches a single handler to the `document`, and runs the selector you give it for every applicable event on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use .live() to delegate this event to the all new elements.